# how we can select last three options from a excel pivot filter using vba, i added the snap

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cbrB.png)    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FPivot_table").PivotFields("Principal Vendor Name")
.Orientation = xlPageField
.Position = 1
End With

added "Principal Vendor Name" as filter, inside this filter we have above 5 values it will varry but need last 3 options to be selected in the filter, i tried using itration didnt get the expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely misunderstood the question in my first answer and have deleted that one.

For `PivotFields` being used as filters, you can change which items are shown by changing the `.Visible` property of each `PivotItem`. To get the table to refresh properly while changing the filter, you have to reset the field before making any changes, which you can do with `PivotField.CurrentPage = "(All)"`

Here's how you would do that:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("MySheet")

    Dim pT As PivotTable
    Set pT = ws.PivotTables("MyPivotTable")
    
    Dim pF As PivotField
    Set pF = pT.PivotFields("MyPivotField")

    pF.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    pF.CurrentPage = "(All)"
    
    For i = 1 To pF.PivotItems.Count
        If i < pF.PivotItems.Count - 2 Then
            pF.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Else
            pF.PivotItems(i).Visible = True
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```